# Get back an icon from the "icon?" file

Tags: macos, finder, folders, icon

I have a external HD with several folders and every folder have a specific icon.

I tried to clean it up with [CleanMyDrive2](https://macpaw.com/cleanmydrive), and now my folders are all back with the usual blue folder icon. Inside of each folder, there is an "icon?" file, but it is visible (it should be invisible so that the folder take the look of the icon, I think). The "icon?" file appear like an executable unix file.

- If I do a preview (by hitting spacebar when the folder is selected) the specific icon appear normaly, but when selecting "get info" the usual blue folder appear
- If I try to copy the "icon?" file in another folder (like on my desktop) an error appear saying that I can't copy this file because it is invisible (but it's not).
- When showing invisible files, no new file appear on the folders
- Unmounting and mounting back my HDD didn't solve the problem
- When copying the "icon?" icon and pasting it on the folder icon, *some of them* get back their icon and *all of the "icon?" files copied* are then deleted (or perhaps, getting back to invisible when the folder gets back its icon).

Is there a way to get back an icon from the "icon?" file ?

I'm running macOS Mojave 14.6

Comment: The HDD was formatted on ExFAT

Comment: Tried both way, none icon shows

Comment: '._Icon?' do not appear on the list, and the size of 'Icon?' is 0. Also, when doing a preview on *foobar* the usual blue folder appear.

Comment: I do understand that without the **._Icon?** file then nothing is going to work (and it appear that this file never shows up doing *ls -al*). But then, why is the icon still appearing in the preview ?

Comment: There are some differences when testing this between **macOS High Sierra** and **macOS Mojave**, however the original _commands_ I presented work instantaneously to restore the custom icon. So without being able to examine what **CleanMyDrive2** actually did you your external HD I have let go of this due to time constraints, sorry.

Comment: No worries ! I was just currious about the fact that the icon is still here when using *preview* and hoped that I would be able to get back what CleanMyDrive2 erased. Those icon are just for a nicer look, nothing important. Thanks !

Comment: Okay, I finally got a chance to run **CleanMyDrive2** on an external HD formatted **ExFAT** and it wiped the necessary _extended attributes_ and _resource fork meta-data_ to remove 50 custom icons on a set of _folders_ to which I had applied the custom icon through the icon on the _folders_ **Get Info** _window_. This did remove/detete the `._Icon?` _files_ which are the actual icons the `Icon?` as a `com.apple.ResourceFork` points to. The actual icons are in a _wrapper_. It also removed the `com.apple.FinderInfo` _meta-data_ from the _folders_ and _resource files_.

Comment: **CleanMyDrive2 is a very nasty destructive program and I would not use it ever again!!!**